# Datastructure that could not be expressed in XML?

Tags: xml, data-structures

What could be the example of a datastructure that could not (sensibly) be expressed in XML? This is an interview question and I can't find anything over this.

Comment: How about anything with a circular reference?

Comment: @cheeken Trivial, assign each node that may be target of a back edge a unique ID and use that ID to refer to it.

Comment: Perhaps an XML file cannot fully describe itself without some kind of XML interpreter (human or machine)?

Comment: @wildplasser Just as easy. Any graph can be done like that.

Comment: @Alex Be more specific. The parse tree of an XML document is just another tree and hence trivial to write in XML. Schemas are also XML. If you had another data structure telling you something about the XML document, you could likely encode that in XML too. It is true that XML is not a programming language and cannot perform an algorithm (on itself or on anything else), but that wasn't the question (it's about data structures).

Comment: @delnan I'm thinking along the lines of "self-reproducing"(?) programs, such that output their own source code. I don't think you can achieve this kind of thing without an interpreter/compiler of sorts.

Comment: In your example, it is the *data* inside the XML that encodes the topology, The structure of the XML is only used to carry this data, not describe its structure.

Comment: @Alex Of course not, because that is not a data structure but an algorithm - read, not asked for.

Comment: @wildplasser By that definition, anything beside a tree is not for XML. That's an unnecessarily restrictive view. When you construct the same implementation of a DAG in a programming language (e.g. `struct Task{string[] depends;};typedef map<string, Task> TaskDAG; `), you also encode the topology in the `dependencies` array, i.e. in data, and not in the types or directly with pointers (which are also just data, just with builtin support). You need indirection in *any* a DAG representation. Except if you want to clone vertices to make it a tree - but that breaks down when modifying the data.

Comment: I think that the purpose of this interview question in not about getting the right answer (if there is one at all), but to see the way you are thinking about it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** I don't know one, and I tried *a lot* of data structures. However, some representations are moderately inefficient, so it's not necessarily the best option, even when perfectly sensible.

That's a tough question. XML is a pretty unrestricted tree, which already covers half of all data structures. Even the most exotic, complicated trees are still trees - I still don't really understand the creation and manipulation of [vBE trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) but I know it's a tree so I can turn a given vBE tree into XML.

Assign each node an ID, or devise another lightweight scheme to refer to a node without making it a child of the referrer, and you can build any kind of graph without much trouble. And graphs are pretty much the be-all and end-all of general data structures. For instance, a directed, cyclic graph goes like this:

```
<graph>
  <vertex id="1">
    <!-- vertex data -->
    <edge to="3"/>
  </vertex>
  <vertex id="2">
    <!-- vertex data -->
    <edge to="1"/>
    <edge to="3"/>
  </vertex>
  <vertex id="3">
    <!-- vertex data -->
    <edge to="1"/>
    <edge to="2"/>
  </vertex>
</graph>
```

It's obvious how this maps to an adjacency list. Even more complicated graphs, like hypergraphs (an edge can contain any number of vertices) are supported, you just need a separate list of edges each of which contains a list of vertex references (see below for lists).

More ordinary data structures are even easier to map to XML:

- Arrays, lists, queues, stacks, and other ordered, flat collections: Make each item a node, put them in a single `<seq>` parent node so they are siblings.
- Tuples (k values): Assign an identifier to each item, then make them attributes. Alternatively, make a `<tuple>` node with k children, and you do not need identifiers as node order (unlike attribute order) is preserved.
- Dictionaries: Treat them as sequence of (key, value) tuples.
- Sets have no order, but every set data structure I am aware of internally orders the elements (by comparison, by hashes and collisions, or simply by insertion order in the naive case). Either use that order, or whatever order the elements are yielded in (if it's different) when you ask the data structure to enumerate its elements.
- Missing a data structure? Encode it as record (replacing pointers with an indirection as used for graphs), then map the record to a node with a child node or attribute for every record member. This gets ugly for some things like linked lists, but for them, a simpler representation exists as outlined above.

None of these representations is as nice as the real deal, but you can work with them just fine and building the real data structure in memory is a matter of a small and simple loop with the right libraries (e.g. lxml in Python, partly due to XPath).

There is one class of data structures which does not map to trees *quite* as easily. Boolean matrices, bit masks, and the like, which gain their efficiency from getting down to a single bit per element, blow up considerably when you use a few dozen bytes for each element (or each `true` element, or each `false` element - the problem remains). However, a less tree-centric encoding can resolve that. You could, for instance, store a base64 string for a one-dimensional bitmask, and use sequences of those for higher dimensions (including boolean matrices). Concatenate the bits to form a number, and encode it in base64 - or rather do it on-line to avoid large-precision arithmetic. The result is not quite XML, but still simple enough to generate and parse.

Therefore, I cannot give you a data structure that cannot be represented sensibly in XML. It's just too general, especially when we make exploit the ability to embed arbitrary binary data in base64 and the like. If you reject that for not being pure XML, then take home: **Bit masks and boolean matrices** cannot be represented *efficiently* in *pure* XML. Note however that a pure XML encoding is still sensible, it just takes a lot of space. And even that can be mitigated if either true of false values are rare (e.g. adjacency matrix of a very dense or sparse graph), by storing only the rarer one and making the other implicit.

However, that does not mean XML is the *best*, or even a good, choice for encoding those data structures. It's a popular data exchange format, but for any given data structure, there are simpler and more efficient representation. So if you do not need the flexibility and can afford some extra work, don't use it. Or use one of the other general-purpose data formats. All of the encodings described above work perfectly in YAML with less verbosity, and some work even better as things like mappings and arrays are built in. Trees become lightly more ugly as you have to encode them as nested records (read: lists/mappings), but that's how you would represent them in a programming language anyway. I'm also pretty sure JSON can handle all of them, but as I did not spend a lot of time generating and parsing it (I did with XML and YAML) I can't say for sure.

Comment: An infinite structure? See my answer

Answer (score 5):

A structure representing an **infinite series of elements**. For example, in scala I can create the **fibonacci** sequence as follows:

```
lazy val fibs: Stream[Int] 
  = 0 #:: 1 #:: ((fibs zip fibs.tail) map { case (n, s) => n + s })
```

How would anyone represent this structure in XML? I guess you could argue that this works :-)

```
<structure lang="scala">
  <[[CDATA [
  lazy val fibs: Stream[Int] 
    = 0 #:: 1 #:: ((fibs zip fibs.tail) map { case (n, s) => n + s })
  ]>
</structure>
```

Comment: it is not the data structure. Actually, it is a function, which returns the numbers of fibonacci sequence, because of lazy evaluation.

Comment: Well, it's a structure that I can get data out of.

Comment: +1 for an interesting idea. But I'm not sure if it counts, because frankly any "infinite data structure" (in Scala, or Haskell, or any other language) is actually some seeding data + some code (or a formula, if you prefer keeping the abstraction) that generates a finite number of elements on demand (and possibly memoizes it). As such, I'm not sure if it counts as data structure. The non-declarative equivalent, a finite data structure + an algorithm, is out of scope because the latter part is not a data structure.

Comment: You could generate an infinite stream of XML elements the same way.

Comment: Does XML allow for infinitely-sized documents? I'm afraid I would have to disagree because *how could this possibly be **well-formed** XML*?

Comment: Sorry, how are you presenting infinite data structures in non-XML? I believe it's an abstraction and any attempt to represent it eventually becomes a function.

Comment: A function is some mapping between a domain `A` and a range `B`, so I'm not sure what your mean by "becomes a function". The structure I have described contains data, which happens to be the fibonacci sequence. I am confused by why you might disagree with my contention that this is "a structure" and that it "contains data"

Comment: That's what the abstraction of lazy evaluation may claim. However: (1) Taken at face value, it is merely an expression, which is then evaluated non-strictly - and would blow up if evaluated strictly. (2) More pragmatically, there is no way to store it, except by storing some representation of the expression (e.g. an AST). That's also what a Haskell implementation does: Thunks are bits of code, not the data they evaluate to. (3) It does not necessarily "contain data" (beside the code/algorithm); a Haskell impl. could not cache the numbers.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Let's distinguish data and algorithms to process the data. Otherwise we can concider everything as data. That's fine rather for functional analysis. Your example with fibonacci sequence is perfect but that would be a bit hard to consume it if you are not a scala-powered pice of code. Also let me mention that XML should be rather human-readable. So we can say "yes, infinite structures cannot be effectivly expressed with XML itself" as well random data or data of multidimensional methaphysics equations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most definitions of the word data structure refer to the pattern in which data is **stored** (stored as opposed to calculated on demand). And it is impossible to actually **store** an infinite sequence of elements, no matter what storage device or language you use.

Answer (score 4):

If this is an interview question, then I humbly suggest that perhaps you *might not want the job* after all...

Answer (score 2):

I think we could not expressed HashTable data structure in XML "sensibly".
Because basic of HashTable says we must get data in O(1) times, and we make it possible in array by doing indexing of each and every object. But in XML its not possible, we have to traverse xml each and every time to get object.

Comment: Interesting answer, because it shows that one needs to distinguish the logical data structure (a map) from the physical data structure (a hash or index implementation of a map). If the question is about physical data structures, then the question becomes a nonsense, because XML is designed for data interchange, and for efficient processing you always have to add physical access paths on top of the raw XML for fast access.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much anything can be expressed in XML. I think you would avoid it when:

1. Encoding/Parsing XML would be too slow for your purpose (eg. in a videogame) or consume too much memory (in a mobile phone app for instance).
2. AND, you don't require the format to be read by anything outside your own application.

Answer (score 1):

> **P.S.: What does "sensible" in the asked question mean?**
>
> > *[...] a data structure that could not (sensibly) be expressed in XML.*
>
> If you write out your XML manually, then a low signal-to-noise ratio (i.e. too many angle brackets, often-repeated element names) could very well be a reason for you to judge the XML as "not sensible".
>
> My answer does not consider such issues. I believe that **XML is more useful as a data exchange format written and read by machines, not humans**, and from this viewpoint, "sensible" means something else (because you no longer do the repetitive typing or the decyphering, and the XML serializer software won't complain either):
>
> > "How difficult is it to *conceptually* map a data structure to a suitable XML schema?"

I suppose this depends on the concrete XML schema used.

XML, by itself, is a very generic format. It isn't so much the XML format that limits what can be expressed in it. When compared to natural language, XML itself is more akin to things like capitalization and punctuation ("orthography") than to grammar. The "grammar", or the structure of valid content, would be more accurately placed in an XML schema (XSD). In this respect, it is unlike most programming languages, which usually have one fixed grammar.

Let's briefly digress and make an analogy. Let's assume that [the Eskimo language has more words for snow than the English language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo_words_for_snow). Does that mean that the English language is incapable of accurately describing the various forms of snow? No, it only means that instead of one precise word, you might need a whole sentence to transfer the same meaning. In other words, the English language is flexible enough to allow circumscriptions.

Getting back to the XML: If you needed an XML schema to describe snow, and it lacks for an element `frobble` that means exactly, *"snow that is as frozen as it usually is after 17 days"*, then perhaps you can introduce the necessary elements into the schema that would allow you to express that very description.

In another programming language, what would you do as a language designer if you found out that your type system wasn't powerful enough to describe some data structure? You might simply *extend* the type system. (For example, generics were not available in Java and C# right from the beginning. It would also be possible to introduce C-style `union`s to C#.) The same thing can be done in XML, only here you wouldn't have to extend the XML specification, nor the XML Schema specification, but the concrete XML schema in use.

To conclude, my main point is this: XML as a format does not put limits on content, only on the content's form of presentation ("orthography"). On the other hand, a concrete XML schema defines what is valid content and what isn't (grammar). You can come up with an arbitrarily simple or complex grammar to suit your needs.

So, I am convinced that it is possible to describe *any* data structure in XML.

Comment: OK you may be right there, but my point is that you can come up with a schema of arbitrary complexity and use that to describe your data structure. Come up with a schema for describing English language sentences, then describe your boolean matrix with *that*.

Comment: OP said "(sensible)" for a reason. An "arbitrarily complex schema" gets out of hand soon, to actually make use of it, it has to be simple enough to comprehend, verify and implement, yet efficient and correct. Implementing a natural language parser or a C++ interpreter is none of that, except perhaps correct, but that's moot when it won't be implemented.

Comment: When I say "arbitrarily complex", I don't say "complex". Make it as complex as it needs to be. The question was whether there are data structures that cannot be expressed in XML. My answer is: most likely not, but instead the XML schema might get more complex for difficult data structures.

Comment: But the question is not just "can you encode every data structure somehow", the answer to that is obviously true. The question is more like "is there a decent, useful encoding for every data structure". Or that's how I understood it anyway.

Comment: I've completely rewritten my answer. I grant to you (@delnan) that the AST example wasn't ideal. Thus my new focus on "linguistics".

Comment: @delnan, what is "sensible" depends heavily on the language used. For example, algebraic data types are well supported in functional languages, e.g. through pattern matching; they probably could be emulated in C, but would be awkward to work with. The OP doesn't mention what kind of type system he has in mind. Therefore "sensible" becomes almost meaningless. Different type systems make different data structures easy to use, or "sensible". Thus my (almost philosophical) answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12942/discussion-between-delnan-and-stakx)

Answer (score 1):

You can represent any data structure in XML, just as you can represent any data structure in a sequence of bits. It's all a question of how convenient the representation is.  For example, XML is not particularly ideal for representing a general graph, but it can certainly be done.

Comment: See my answer: what about an infinite structure?

Comment: There's nothing in the XML specification that says an XML document has to be finite.

Comment: But how could there be a closing tag? It's quite blatantly obvious that, in order to be well-formed, the content must be finite

Comment: Not quite. It has to be finite if you want to determine in a finite time whether it is well-formed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Every data structure can be expressed using xml.

Every data can be expressed as zeros and ones, or as "bytes". You can encode every data into printable form, e.g. using base64 encoding, then you just write

```
<data>your_base64_data</data>
```

and you have XML! :D

Comment: That's no "sensible" representation. It's a cheap way out, like bringing up (only) turing completeness in answer to "is language X or Y better for Z?" (which is flawed itself, but let's ignore that).